# Escaping parentheses in perl backticks for bash command

Tags: bash, perl

I have been using backticks for years but this is the first time I have tried using a command with a parentheses.  I am getting an error that I cannot figure out.

I have tried putting in double quotes and escaping with the `\` in multiple places, but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

COMMAND
the `$file5` and `$file6` are perl variables, not bash.

```
@array = `/usr/bin/join -j 1 -t, <(cat $file5 | awk -F, '{print \$3","\$1}' | sort) <( cat $file6 | awk -F, '{print \$3","\$1}' | sort) `
```

ERROR: 
AH01215: sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `(', referer:

Comment: I think the `sh` in the error-message is the big hint here. Process substitution (the `<(...)` syntax) is not specified by POSIX, and it seems that your system's `sh` doesn't support it. You might need to explicitly invoke Bash, or else coordinate the process communication yourself.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do that directly in your Perl program?

Answer (score 2):

Backticks use `/bin/sh`, and while `<( ... )` is something recognized by `bash`, it's not recognized by the bourne shell. If you use backticks, you will need to use

```perl
my $bash_cmd = ...;
my @lines = `bash -c $bash_cmd`;
```

Building `sh` and `bash` shell commands can be done using [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote).

```perl
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $file5_quoted = shell_quote($file5);
my $file6_quoted = shell_quote($file6);

my $awk_cmd = shell_quote("awk", "-F,", '{print $3","$1}');

my $bash_cmd = '/usr/bin/join -j 1 -t,'
   . " <( $awk_cmd $file5_quoted | sort )"
   . " <( $awk_cmd $file6_quoted | sort )";

my $sh_cmd = shell_quote("bash", "-c", $bash_cmd);
my @lines = `$sh_cmd`;
```

We can use [IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple)'s `capturex` to avoid launching more shells than needed, as well as to provide error checking. To do this, replace the last two lines of the above with the following:

```perl
use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );

my @lines = capturex("bash", "-c", $bash_cmd);
```

Answer (score -2):

One workaround is to create a shell script that accepts the two filenames from perl, processes the join using those two input files, and return the result to the perl array.

```
#1. Create join.sh that contains these four lines:

    cat $1 | awk -F, '{print $3","$1}' | sort > 1.out
    cat $2 | awk -F, '{print $3","$1}' | sort > 2.out
    /usr/bin/join -j 1 -t, 1.out 2.out
    rm 1.out 2.out


#2. Modify your perl statement to call join.sh as follows:

    @array=`join.sh $file5 $file6`;
```

Comment: Lack of explanation. Missing shebang. Suffers from four code injection bugs. Bad choice of file names. ([Fixed code](https://pastebin.com/TBKaUBhS))